# uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$ uniformally

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question is:

> Let $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ a series converges uniformly on $I$ to
>    $S(x)$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$.

My try: $\forall N\in\mathbb N$, we have $f_N(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}f_n(x)-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}f_n(x)$, so the statement is proved if I prove that

$$f_n(x),g_n(x)\to f(x),g(x)\text{ uniformly on }J\implies\\ f_n(x)+g_n(x)\to f(x)+g(x) \text{ uniformly on }J.$$ 
On the one hand:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in J}|f_n(x)-f(x)+g_n(x)-g(x)|\leq&\quad\text{(triangle inequality) }\\
\limsup\limits_{x\in J}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|g_n(x)-g(x)|}=0+0=0.
\end{align*}$$

Now I'm in trouble proving that $\limsup\limits_{x\in J}{|f_n(x)+g_n(x)-f(x)-g(x)|}\geq 0$. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know:
$\forall x\in J:|f_n(x)+g_n(x)-f(x)-g(x)|\ge0 $
then:
$\limsup\limits_{x\in J}{|f_n(x)+g_n(x)-f(x)-g(x)|}\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

It easier to work with the remainder $R_n(x) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty f_k(x)$. By hypothesis, we know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x} |R_n(x)| = 0.
$$

Since $f_n(x) = R_n(x) - R_{n+1}(x)$, we deduce
$$
\sup_x |f_n(x)| \leq \sup_x |R_n(x)| + \sup_x |R_{n+1}(x)| \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0.
$$

Comment: Sorry for illteracy but how $f_n(x)\to 0$ uniformly in your solution?

Comment: What do you mean? I proved that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_x |f_n(x)| = 0$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: it is not clear. Check the title.

Comment: @Ju'x you showed that $\sup|f_n(x)|$ is less than something tends to zero. How it proved the limit is exactly zero?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis: $\sup_x |f_n(x)|$ is non-negative. Do you know the squeeze theorem?

Comment: yes. I didn't think about it. thanks.